# Nightwatch JS: Browser.execute does not execute javascript

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

The goal of my test is to check if the textfield input is empty

When I use the browser.execute() command in Nightwatch and I want to add some simple javascript to check if textfield is empty then the block is being skipped by Nightwatch. If I would run the JS code in dev tools, it works but when I transform it into Nightwatch it fails. I could be misunderstanding the concept of browser.execute, so I would hope someone could tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
Nightwatch code

this.api.execute(
       function() {
        let element = document.getElementById('autocomplete-input').value;
        console.log(element);
             if(element.length == 0 || element === ""){
             console.log('Element is empty')
            }
          })
        },


JS code

     function testing1() {
       let element = document.getElementById('autocomplete-input').value;
       console.log(element);
          if(element.length == 0 && element === ""){
          console.log('Element is empty')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look up .execute() in [Nightwatch Docs](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/execute.html) it requires a body, an array of arguments which will be passed to the function and an optional call back function. Since you've the body, adding an empty array should do the job.

```
browser.execute(function testing1() {
           let element = document.getElementById('autocomplete-input').value;
           console.log(element);
              if(element.length == 0 && element === ""){
              console.log('Element is empty')
        }
    }, [])
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me! Appreciate it!

Comment: Sure, I will let you know tomorrow :)